# Magento 2 "toOptionArray()" function

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, adminform

Anybody please let me know how to define a "toOptionArray()" kind of function in Magento 2 such that any "array" (I have "array" formatted data not object[] format) can be defined and assigned to Admin custom form "select" field.

Like below:

```
public function getBannerEffects()
        {
                return array(
                array('value' => 'none', 'label'=>__('None')),
                        array('value' => 'blindX', 'label'=>__('Blind X')),
                        array('value' => 'blindY', 'label'=>__('Blind Y')),
                        array('value' => 'blindZ', 'label'=>__('Blind Z')),
                        array('value' => 'cover', 'label'=>__('Cover')),
                        array('value' => 'curtainX', 'label'=>__('Curtain X')),
                        array('value' => 'curtainY', 'label'=>__('Curtain Y')),
                        array('value' => 'fade', 'label'=>__('Fade')),
                        array('value' => 'fadeZoom', 'label'=>__('Fade Zoom')),
                        array('value' => 'growX', 'label'=>__('Grow X')),
                        array('value' => 'growY', 'label'=>__('Grow Y')),
                        array('value' => 'scrollUp', 'label'=>__('Scroll Up')),
                        array('value' => 'scrollDown', 'label'=>__('Scroll Down')),
                        array('value' => 'scrollLeft', 'label'=>__('Scroll Left')),
                        array('value' => 'scrollRight', 'label'=>__('Scroll Right')),
                        array('value' => 'scrollHorz', 'label'=>__('Scroll Horizontal')),
                        array('value' => 'scrollVert', 'label'=>__('Scroll Vertical')),
                        array('value' => 'shuffle', 'label'=>__('Shuffle')),
                        array('value' => 'toss', 'label'=>__('Toss')),
                        array('value' => 'turnUp', 'label'=>__('Turn Up')),
                        array('value' => 'turnDown', 'label'=>__('Turn Down')),
                        array('value' => 'turnLeft', 'label'=>__('Turn Left')),
                        array('value' => 'turnRight', 'label'=>__('Turn Right')),
                        array('value' => 'uncover', 'label'=>__('Uncover')),
                        array('value' => 'wipe', 'label'=>__('Wipe')),
                        array('value' => 'zoom', 'label'=>__('Zoom'))
                );
        }
```

Can this be declared in Model or Helper ?

How to assign this data to custom module Admin panel form "select" field ?

Answer (score 4):

You create source model 
class RedPage implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface

```
public function toOptionArray() {
        return [
            [
                'value' => 0,
                'label' => __('Page1'),
            ],
            [
                'value' => 1,
                'label' => __('Page2'),
            ],
            [
                'value' => 2,
                'label' => __('Page3'),
            ],
        ];

    }
```

Comment: `@Pratik` nope, it's not working. It crashes the page immeidately.

Comment: Please send me your code and also magento 2 version

Comment: Magento 2.0.0 stable version, will post code tomorrow for this.

Comment: It works for me. Thx @Pratik

Answer (score 0):

In `system.xml` file custom **select field**

```
<field id="select_field" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="2" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Custom Select Field</label>
                    <source_model>Learning\Custom\Model\Config\Source\CustomeField</source_model>
                </field>
```

and you should create Model file to load the select field `toOptionsArray()` values

```
<?php

namespace Learning\Custom\Model\Config\Source;

class CustomeField implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{


    public function toOptionArray()
    {

        $attributesArrays = array();

        $attributesArrays[0] =array(
            'label' => '0',
            'value' => 'One'
        );
        $attributesArrays[1] =array(
            'label' => '1',
            'value' => 'Two'
        );
        $attributesArrays[2] =array(
            'label' => '3',
            'value' => 'Three'
        );
       return $attributesArrays;

    }

}
```

let me know if it's not working..