# Magento 2: How to create gird in configuration

Tags: magento2, configuration, system-config, system-configuration

I am trying to create a new configuration for checking postcodes.
Is it possible to add so many postcodes rather than creating one text field
So I can pick which ever postcode by using 
type="select"

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question, I would suggest you create a select or multi-select field in Configuration. From which you can select whichever postcode you like.

Add code for select/multi-select field in Namespace/Module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml something like,

```
<!-- For Select Type Configuration -->
<field id="postcode" translate="label" sortOrder="1" type="select" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
   <label>Select Postcode</label>
   <source_model>Namespace\Module\Model\Adminhtml\System\Postcode</source_model>
</field>


<!-- For Multiselect -->
<field id="postcode_multiselect" translate="label" sortOrder="2" type="multiselect" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
   <label>Select Beauty Banners</label>
   <source_model>Namespace\Module\Model\Adminhtml\System\Postcode\Multiselect</source_model>
</field>
```

Created Source Model file to get ToArray function just like implemented in below link,
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/92863/45214